# Maths Problem based on trains

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If A train runs at $70$km/h, it reaches its destination late by $12$ minutes. But if it runs at $80$km/h it is late by $3$ minutes. What is the correct time to cover the journey?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I retagged as algebra-precalculus. Edit further if any other appropriate tag comes to your mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $d$ be the distance (in kilometers) for the journey and let $t$ be the correct time (in hours) to cover the journey.

If the train travels at the correct rate, then it would travel at a speed of $s=\frac{d\mathrm{~km}}{t\mathrm{~hr}}$.

Now, we know that at $70$ km/hr, $d$ would be covered in $t+\frac{12}{60}$ hours; at $80$ km/hr, $d$ would be covered in $t+\frac{3}{60}$ hours.

Thus, $70=\frac{d}{t+\frac{12}{60}}$ and $80=\frac{d}{t+\frac{3}{60}}$.  Can you do the rest?

Comment: What will be the answer?

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $t+\frac{12}{60}$ and multiply the second equation by $t+\frac{3}{60}$.  The right sides of the two new equations would both be equal to $d$.  Then equate the left sides of the two new equations and you would get one equation in one unknown: $t$.  Solve for $t$.

Comment: The first step in solving mathematical word problems is to identify the variables and their appropriate units of measure.  The second step is to rewrite all the given information in terms of these variables.  The third step is to solve the equations resulting from the second step.  The last step is to rewrite the mathematical statement into a word statement.  (And of course, you'll need to check if the answer is correct.)